# Q&A style construed as help

Tags: discussion

I shared [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519916/count-of-3-digit-numbers-with-at-least-one-digit-as-9) question with an answer. Now it has been put on hold. I wonder if I need to mention in question itself that I am posting my own answer. Or maybe, this site expects questions to be of high level. My not-so-good question is getting not-so-good reaction.

Comment: Well, you've seen the reasons giving for closing the question. Had you indicated in the question that you were about to post your own answer, I doubt there would have been a vote to close. But, what's the purpose in posting a question when you intend to post an answer as well? By the way, your question got three answers in addition to your own --- I'd say that's a *very* good reaction.

Comment: The idea of being able to ask questions and answer them yourself is that the question and answer would be of use to future visitors. The fact that this is a fairly easy and very specific problem means that it does not satisfy this.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- I actually expect a very bright future for this site. There are various kinds of visitors. A good percentage of 'future' visitors may not find that question fairly easy. So I just thought of adding that as I consider this site as a bank for questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson- I was not *about to*, I actually posted both question and answer together. Maybe the moderator must automatically highlight that it's Q$A format. I believe many are not aware that there is one such option before we actually post a question.

Comment: @Ramit I agree that it might not be easy to everybody, but it is very specific. I would argue (although not very strongly without thinking harder about it first) that this site will be *more* useful to future visitors if it has lots of Q&As addressing general conceptual problems, which are not drowned out by model answers to homework-style questions, particularly if these answers don't suggest how somebody is supposed to come up with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is acceptable use of the site.  I've done the same thing, when I've written a question, and along the way have come up with an answer, but I might not have come up with the canonical answer (it might be, but I can't be sure without asking).

**I hazard a guess that the question was closed mostly because people did not notice it was you that wrote the first answer.**  Answers don't show up on the review queue, and, even when not using the review queue, it takes some effort to realise that the OP posted an answer.

So the original version of the question:

> Find the number of 3 digit numbers (repetitions allowed) such that at least one of the digit is 9.​

looks like a problem statement question, and probably was closed as such.  So comments like the one you subsequently added can be helpful in explaining why you'd want to do this:

> I've posted my answer below. If there is a better way to solve this question, I would be glad to learn about that.

Comment: The [tag:alternative-proof] tag is probably useful in cases like this one.

Comment: I disagree. While the general idea of SE is that one should be allowed to do this, it is almost never a good fit for MSE in particular. The case you mention is one where it can make sense, but the OP has given no indication that this was his reason for posting both question and answer.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- I think it should get highlighted automatically that it's a Q&A format.

Comment: @Ramit I am not sure what you mean by that. Where should it get highlighted? And highlighting that the format is Q&A seems to be counter to what you are arguing here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- When we post question and answer together, it should be highlighted (beside the title perhaps) that it's a Q&A format so that other users don't construe it as a help-seeking question.